# How does one use multiple fonts in CSS?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have just started making a website and wish to include multiple fonts. I'm new to HTML and CSS and don't quite get how they interact. When looking up a tutorial for how to do so, it shows only HTML, despite explicitly saying CSS.

[The W3Schools tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_font-family) I am currently using shows this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .p1 {
      font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    }
    
    .p2 {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    
    .p3 {
      font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>CSS font-family</h1>
  <p class="p1">This is a paragraph, shown in the Times New Roman font.</p>
  <p class="p2">This is a paragraph, shown in the Arial font.</p>
  <p class="p3">This is a paragraph, shown in the Lucida Console font.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Doesn't the header define this as an HTML file? How does CSS play into this?

Comment: CSS is everything between `<style>` and `</style>` They are linked by the `class` attribute matching the `.p1`, `.p2`, `.p3` selectors.

Answer (score 1):

The [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style) tag (a.k.a. what you are mentioning) specifically allows CSS to be embed into a HTML document. It can use any CSS, as long as it is encapsulated within the tag.

```html
<style>
    body {
        background-color: #333;
    }
</style>
```

This is different from the linking of a external CSS file which uses the `link` element:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
```

However, you can also use the `style` attribute to add styles to an individual element on its tag's HTML.

```html
<a href="https://google.com" style="color: black;">Google</a>
```

For the relationship between the two, HTML (Hyper Text Markup Language) is the basic blueprint / building blocks for the page and the structure it should be rendered in, while CSS (Cascading Style Sheets) describes what the page should look like. They are tightly knit and are meant to be used together. That is why the style tag *specifically* includes CSS in HTML. You can include both CSS and JavaScript in HTML or you can link them through external files.

Comment: So is the syntax of CSS by extension, the same as HTML?

Comment: No, they have different syntaxes, however by using these tags you can use CSS in HTML. They are different things that can be used together to form a single web page.

Answer (score 0):

Everything between the tags `<style>`and `</style>` is the css here.
There are other ways to integrate css.
You can attach a style directly to an html element:

```
<p style="text-align: center; color: green;">
  this paragraph will be centered and green  
</p>
```

Or you can write your styles into an extra textfile and link to this file in the header of your page

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    ...
</head>
```